# creating a 1ms delay using blackfin

Tags: c, timer

I'm trying to use black fin 533, to create a delay of 1ms using one of its timers, I read the datasheet but I can't understand how to set a 1ms delay.
here is the datasheet
http://www.analog.com/media/en/dsp-documentation/processor-manuals/ADSP-BF533_hwr_rev3.6.pdf

Please I need clarification of timer width and timer period.

Comment: It Does not even sound like you have decided upon how to use the timer let alone made an attempt at writing code to configure the timer.  Please decide on how you want to use the timer (there are 3 of them) then rephrase your question to be more specific.  For example, these timers may be used to dim lights.  Or make music.  Or control servo motors.

Comment: I just want to make a delay of 1ms. is that possible with those timers ? I need to monitor the status flag correct ? but how to adjust the period,..etc to make a 1ms delay. by polling only, not by interrupts

Comment: Hardware timers get their time base from the processor's oscillator.  You have to know how fast the processor is running.  Or you can guess, pick numbers to load into the timers, try and time, say, 10 seconds.  If it works, great!  If it doesn't, make another guess.  It would be quicker if you already knew the processor's clock.

Comment: #define CLK_IN              12288000    /* Input clock in Hz */

Comment: Good, you have taken the first step in figuring out how to use the timers.  Now if you have a specific problem with the timers please re-phrase your question.  Otherwise read page 62+ of the manual you linked to.  Stackexchange comments are not a good place to chat.  Comments are meant to help people refine their questions and answers.

Comment: I don't know the difference between timer period and timer width

Comment: A delay *from* what *to* what?  Also a millisecond is in the time range where software methods become possible, at least depending on what your software stack / OS is like.

Comment: @ChrisStratton just a 1ms delay. I know I can do it using software methods, but I need an accurate delay of 1ms. I'm not using any OS.

Comment: There is no such thing as "just" a delay, because delay is measured between things, and what is and is not possible depends on what those things are.  If you want this question to survive here, you will have to supply *all* of the missing pieces to make it clear and specific.  At present it is unanswerable, and as a result the process of closing it is well underway.

Comment: @ChrisStratton would you explain from the datasheet, what's timer period and what's timer width, is the width, the width of the square wave ? and the period is the period of the square wave ?

Comment: I can see, but you probably can not, that 3 people voted on your answer.  They probably do not like it because the title and the specific question you finally asked do not match.  No guarantees, but if you clean up your question they may pull back their negative votes.

Comment: @Andre Please look at http://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask Most of your questions look like you want a handout answer. You also haven't posted any code, please post what you have found in your research and more on your problems. Post a specific question that readers can answer. Be professional and use proper capitalization and grammar (that also goes for the title) Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Please I need clarification of timer width and timer period.

In general terms, if the timer is configured to generates a train of pulses, the width the output is active is normally referring to as the duty cycle.  This is called [Pulse Width Modulation (PWM)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pulse-width_modulation) and can be useful in [modulating the brightness of a, for example, LED](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/Fade).

Some or all the timers in this chip can also measure the pulse width of external signals.  Such a feature can be used to decode, for example, serial communication signals.

When a timer is configured to generates a train of pulses, the period is the time between the same event in that train of pulses.  For instance the time between, say, the rising edge of the clock of a 1KHz signal is 1ms.